# I include some shortcuts in my .profile but I want these to be activated at login time .. see below

Tags: shortcuts, keys

I include some shortcuts in my *.profile* but I want these to be activated at login time by adding my home ¨profile¨ in */etc/profile*.
But it require super user permission. How to add this. I am guessing (if I remember good) to add a line in the */etc/password* file, is this right?

Please clarify how?

Comment: `/etc/password` ? No.  to issue a command that requires super user permission you preface it with sudo. But make sure you know what you are doing first as with ultimate power comes ultimate responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a useful link. http://linux-training.be/security/ch04.html 
There are different kinds of profiles.

1. If for yourself only, you can just make changes under ~/.profile (not /etc/profile which is typically edited via sudo to impact all user accounts). Shell will load both /etc/profile and ~/.profile. changes in ~/.profile are more for personal changes.
2. Please do `source ~/.profile` after changes. Without this command, new changes will not be loaded, unless you reboot/re-login to your account.
3. Different shell loads different profile. The answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45805) is pretty comprehensive.